# Tab not selecting with change in selected form

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a tabforms in my application and whenever i open the multiple forms the tabs open in usual manner but  whenever i open the form which is already opened the selected tab doesnt get changed.it gets stuck to the tab which is opened at last.My code is here.

```
private void Form1_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ActiveMdiChild == null)
            tabForms.Visible = false;
        // If no any child form, hide tabControl 
        else
        {
            this.ActiveMdiChild.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            // Child form always maximized 

            // If child form is new and no has tabPage, 
            // create new tabPage 
            if (this.ActiveMdiChild.Tag == null)
            {
                // Add a tabPage to tabControl with child 
                // form caption 

                TabPage tp = new TabPage(this.ActiveMdiChild.Text);
                tp.Tag = this.ActiveMdiChild;
                tp.Parent = tabForms;
                tabForms.SelectedTab = tp;


                SwapTabPages(tp);

                this.ActiveMdiChild.Tag = tp;
                this.ActiveMdiChild.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(ActiveMdiChild_FormClosed);
            }

            if (!tabForms.Visible) tabForms.Visible = true;

        }
    }


private void ActiveMdiChild_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Destroy the corresponding Tabpage when closing MDI child form
        if (tabForms.HasChildren)
        {
            ((sender as Form).Tag as TabPage).Dispose();
        }            
        //If no Tabpage left
        else if (!tabForms.HasChildren)
        {
            tabForms.Visible = false;                
        }            
    }

    private void tabForms_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((tabForms.SelectedTab != null) && (tabForms.SelectedTab.Tag != null))
            (tabForms.SelectedTab.Tag as Form).Select();            
    }
```

Comment: This is not a question.  This is one ridiculously long run-out sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer

```
 else
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < tabForms.TabCount; i++)
                        {
                            if (tabForms.TabPages[i].Text == this.ActiveMdiChild.Text.ToString())
                                {
                                    tabForms.SelectedTab = tabForms.TabPages[i];
                                            break;
                                }
                        }
                }                  
                if (!tabForms.Visible) tabForms.Visible = true;
```